# Get Angle from Gyro

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gyroscope

I am working on a project, and part of it needs to measure the rotation of the device. I assume that the most efficient way to do this would be with the gyroscope, but please correct me if I am wrong. I really have no idea where to start, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to start by including the `CoreMotion` framework. Then refer to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a good outline of the `CMMotionManager` class.

The actual implementation is very easy - implement the delegate and tell the manager that you want to start receiving notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Core Motion framework available in iOS starting 4.0. It provides a lot of ready stuff to work gyro and accelerometer at high level without need to work will low level data.